# Same package installed several times

Tags: rpm

I installed an older version of a package with "rpm -i --force package-oldversion.rpm". Now I realize that didn't remove the new version. So i have two packages installed.

What can I do to revert this (except removing both?) thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove both, then reinstall the one you actually want. It's the only way to be sure that you haven't got a mixture of two installations at the same time.